# :wq, or, giving up mod status

Tags: discussion, moderation

I sent an email to the Stack Exchange team asking to resign my mod status.

I've been active for almost five years, since the start of the private beta in February 2015. I feel that I've learned all that I wanted to learn and feel rather "Vimmed out". I don't see that changing in the near future, so hanging on to my mod status doesn't seem right; better for an actually active member of the community to take it.

Comment: You have truly been a motor for this community and I completely share Ben's opinion: When I was a new Vimmer and a new comer to this site your answers have always been interesting, insightful and respectful and that really helped getting this community on its feet. You have truly been an inspiration as a mod and it's been a pleasure to share this site with you. I hope to see you once in a while on Reddit!

Comment: I'm sorry to see you go, Carpetsmoker (dunno, it just feels odd to call you Martin). But I hope it's just moderation you're giving up, not Stack Exchange altogether. I believe this shit storm can be patched over in the long run, and the platform itself is too valuable to give up, so I continue (though I haven't been around on Vi & Vim as much I should have).

If you're ever in Japan, do feel free to ping me!

Comment: Martin, sad to see you go. Thank you for what you have done for the community and for teaching by example how to write great answers.

Comment: (regarding your entry on the Meta.SE list: would you be OK if your entry is moved to the “for their own reasons” section, rather than removing it completely?)

Comment: I'd rather not @amon, the timing is just coincidental; I had already decided to resign a few weeks ago. I was just annoyed (even angry) about the entire thing as I feel that Monica has been done a great injustice, and so I vented a bit here after catching up on recent events after several days of travel. I am certainly not "resigning out of protest" and sent the email before I even learned that Monica was fired. I've taken that section out, and regret I put it in there in the first place.

Comment: I already stopped visiting regularly months ago @muru; mostly because my interests have just shifted elsewhere. The Vim site is pretty isolated from general Stack Exchange drama and Stack Overflow levels of community abrasiveness (which is why I stopped contributing on SO, [wrote about that over here](https://arp242.net/stackoverflow.html)), so my disappointment in SE doesn't really affect what I do (or don't do) on this site.

Comment: Thanks for everything! Good luck going forward.

Answer (score 11):

Martin,

I have always enjoyed your input to discussions and your knack for remaining level-headed when the situation spirals.

Your presence here now and previously as Carpetsmoker was a reliable fixture of the site for me, and one of the ones that made it feel like a community. As a relatively new user, getting to see that name crop up now and then made me feel like I knew a bit about the community—and eventually, like I was part of it and its dialogue. Thank you for contributing to that.

I will be sad to see you go, but I respect your decision. It is hard to remain where one feels uncomfortable.

Thank you for serving me and this community. I wish you well.

---

P. S. I’m rather close friends with a few Dutch folks in the Nijmegen area. When time permits in the (possibly distant) future, I hope to visit them again. If it all works out, I’ll buy you a beverage of your choosing.

Comment: PPS I dont know how votes are generally understood on Qs like this, so Ive refrained from casting mine.

Comment: Thanks :-) `I’m rather close friends with a few Dutch folks in the Nijmegen area. When time permits in the (possibly distant) future, I hope to visit them again. If it all works out, I’ll buy you a beverage of your choosing` -> Cheers! I don't actually live in the Netherlands though (haven't for many years). I just moved from Ireland to Bali last Monday! No idea how long I'll be here, but if you're ever around then I'll be happy to buy you a drink back ;-)

Comment: Works for me @MartinTournoij :)