# March 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

> **UPDATE:** The election [has now been scheduled](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1512/1009).

---

This community last had moderators appointed in [September 2018](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1459/1841), so it's been a while... In addition to that, you may have noticed that two of our mods - [Martin](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497/1841) and [James](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1506/1841) - have stepped down from their moderator position. Once again I want to thank them for the amazing work they have done and their great impact on our community.

Since we still have the "beta" label, we qualify for [a pro-tem election where pro-tem moderators are now elected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332180/208518), just like "regular" moderators. As such, we are looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere this month to find a replacement for our two previous moderators, which would take the count to three moderators, including myself. Even if the moderation needs is pretty low, I believe that having more people moderating our site would be highly beneficial as it would allow to distribute the moderation powers which is always better to avoid (even involuntary) abuse of said powers.

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in March '20.

**NOTE**: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: statox: Sorry I'm late to the party... Is this election happening any time soon? (I primarily use StackExchange on mobile so I sometimes end up missing announcements and events that are way more prominent on the website...)

Comment: I [just scheduled it](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1512/1009), @filbranden :)

Comment: Wait, what @filbranden? How do you write your long and detailed answers on mobile?! Of course, whatever works for you, I'm just surprised.

Comment: @MartinTournoij The best part is testing them on DroidVim 

Comment: @filbranden I use the unmaintained app 

Answer (score 10):

I would be willing to run. I'll wait 'til nominations to say more :)

Answer (score 3):

Willing to become a moderator here too.

(I guess main thing is I should start paying attention to Meta... Ooops!)

Comment: Meta is pretty uneventful and quiet here; so not much to pay attention to really  This is a good thing, the site runs itself without too much troubles!